# How do I record the highest value in a variable

Tags: java, algorithm, jtextfield

I have a variable and I need to find the highest value that was there. That value constantly changes. I need to put that highest value in a textfield.

//This is full program. Posting the code won't help.

I will try to explain the program:

It's Heads or Tails. You press two buttons, heads and tails. And there is a combo JTextField, where it writes how many times in a row you get it right. And the highest value that was in Combo JTextField I need to put in the Highscore JTextField.

Comment: How far did you get? Could you post your existing code?

Comment: Edited it, hope you understand now.

Comment: You dont have to post all the code, you can make a snippet showing what you have tried.

Comment: @AlexSS highest value mean?

Comment: Like int combo = 5 and then int combo changes to 6.The highest value till now is 6.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add another variable for the maximum:

```
SomeType currentValue, maximumValue;

//Encapsulate currentValue and maximumValue
void setValue(SomeType value){
    currentValue = value;

    //update the maximum
    if(value.compareTo(maximumValue) > 0)
        maximumValue = value;
}

SomeType getMaximum(){
    return maximumValue;
}

SomeType getCurrent(){
    return currentValue;
}
```