# Static Float variable only stores highest value assigned; need it to store most recent

Tags: c++

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760854/how-do-i-record-the-highest-value-in-a-variable) seemed to be the closest; my program is similar, but my question is slightly different.

I'm having trouble seeing why the output of this program is "5,5" instead of "5,4". I was under the impression that the value "4" was immediately assigned to the "static float" variable "m" once the maxvalue function was called.

If that is the case, why is 5 the output instead of 4?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float keepmax(float f) {
    static float m = f;
    if(f>m) 
        m = f;
    return m;
}
int main() {
    cout << keepmax(5) << endl;
    cout << keepmax(4) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please remove all unnecessary whitespace from your proigram, properly indent it.

Comment: I think that the first iterration of your function assign the value 5 to the variable m. At the second iterration , because m is already define, it might just skip this instruction and continue.

Comment: I'd recommend reading on static keyword inside functions in C++. In short, their initialized only on the first entry to the function. All future calls do not reinitialize it. Common use case could be a counter of function calls: static int s_called = 0; ++s_called;.

Comment: Because the static will continue holding its value even after the function has returned. Hence when you call it the second time, it still retained '5' as the highest value.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, a `static` variable declared within a function scope will be created and initialized once for all non-recursive calls to that function.

NOTE: Recursive calls effect on static variable initializations are undefined behavior according to the C++ standard.

C++ Standard 6.7 Paragraph 4:

> If control re-enters the declaration recursively while the variable is being initialized, the behavior is undefined.

Example:

```
int foo(int i) {
    static int s = foo(2*i); // recursive call - undefined
    return i+1;`
}
```

---

The first time your function enters the `keepmax` function, your `static float m` variable is initialized to the value passed in, which in this case is `5`. From this point on, the variable has been created and initialized and the `static float m = f;` statement will, in essence, be skipped over.

The second time your function enters `keepmax`, `m` still has the value `5` from the first call, and the execution (essentially) "jumps over" the `static float m = f;` statement and goes directly to the comparison. Because `m` equals `5` and `f` equals `4`, the comparison `(f>m)` is false (as `4` is not greater than `5`), and the subsequent assignment never occurs.

Comment: "Recursive calls effect on static variable initializations are undefined behavior according to the C++ standard"  - this refers to something like `int f() { static int x = f() + 5; }`   - it is fine for the function to have recursive calls so long as the recursion is not actually part of the initializer

Comment: That is what I was referring to by that. I will include the example from the standard.

Answer (score 0):

> I was under the impression that the value "4" was immediately assigned to the "static float" variable "m" once the maxvalue function was called.

You where under wrong impression, that is not assignment but initialization, and it only happens once when execution flow goes through that code the first time, that's how local static variables work. If you want that variable to change value every time, you need to make it non static:

```
float m = f;
```

or you can also make assignment happen every time:

```
static float m;
m = f;
```

but then it does not make any sense to make this variable static (unless this assignment is done conditionally)

Comment: not exactly so: if he wanted it initialized every time, he'd have to make it non-static, if he wishes for it to be assigned value of f every time, it suffices to move it to another expression, i.e.: m = f;

Comment: @hauron actually that was first variant of my answer, but then I realized that it does not make any sense to make it static.

Comment: judging by the name of the function, OP wishes to remember only the max value. I suppose OP is just asking why the code behaves as it does - since she or he may not know what static does when used on function scope variables...

Comment: @hauron this is correct; I do need my function to perform this way. It works fine, I just didn't understand that the initialization of a static variable only happens once. I'll have to take your advice and read up on it again. Thanks Slava

Answer (score 0):

Because the static will continue holding its value even after the function has returned. Hence when you call it the second time, it still retained '5' as the highest value.